# WPF Grid - Auto-sizing with minimum height constraints

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout, expression-blend

#### Background

I need a grid with the following layout properties:

1. 4 rows: header, main content, sub-content, footer
2. The header is static content which isn't really affected by resize
3. The main content needs to fill up all available space, with a minimum height of 180
4. The sub-content is a RTB that can shrink and grow. This sub-content can eat up some of the main-contents space, but should always leave 180 pixels for the main-content. The sub-content should ideally only take up the minimum amount of area it needs. If there isn't much room left in the grid, the RTB should stop growing and instead enable its internal scrollviewer.
5. The footer is like the header, static content unaffected by resize

#### The problem

The sub-content (`RTB`) isn't auto-sizing itself to fit within the remaining space, nor is the vertical scroll-bar being enabled. This is causing anything below the main content to clip outside of the window.

#### Question

How can I get the `RichTextBox` to shrink so that the footer is shown, allowing the user to scroll through the hidden `RichTextBox` content, while simultaneously allowing the `RichTextBox` to expand if the user stretches the window?

*Below you will find a SSCCE which demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve and the issues that it's causing*:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        MinWidth="200" MinHeight="300" Width="200" Height="300">

    <Grid>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="180"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="Red"/>

        <RichTextBox Grid.Row="2"
                     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                     Height="Auto"
                     Margin="0,5,0,0"
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                     BorderBrush="#FF818181"
                     BorderThickness="0.5"
                     Background="#FFEEEEEE"
                     FontSize="14">
            <FlowDocument>
                <List>
                    <ListItem>
                        <Paragraph>Lorem</Paragraph>
                        <Paragraph>IpSum</Paragraph>
                        <Paragraph>Lorem</Paragraph>
                        <Paragraph>IpSum</Paragraph>
                    </ListItem>
                </List>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Text="Footer" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

#### Here is an image of the window when it's at its minimum size:

[image]

#### Here is an image of the window when it has been stretched to show all:

[image]

#### Extra information

I know that if I set the sub-content `RowDefinition` to `*` then the `RichTextBox` works fine, **except** for the fact it takes too much room when the window is expanded. I need this area to take as much room as `Auto` while behaving like `*`.

Comment: Row Definitions 1 & 2 will both need to be ` * ` but using percentages (like 7* & 3* respectively) to invoke the embedded ScrollViewer in RTB. This should also alleviate the footer hiding issue. You'll just need to decide what percentages of each you want displayed (keep your min-height values though obviously).

Comment: I'm currently using 8* and 3* until I have a better solution, but depending on screen size, the 3* is either larger or smaller than the preferred size. Basic sub-content on a large screen has a lot of blank space which could be used by the main-content, while complex sub-content is limited to an area instead of using unused main-content space.

Comment: Sounds like something better visualized than described since I'm having trouble picturing the intent vs result. I would likely just incorporate min & max values for height to get the desired result.

Comment: As standard, the main-content should take up most of the room, but sometimes, a selected item may have a lot of content to put into the RichTextBox. In this scenario, it is better to have a larger sub-content area to avoid having to scroll through the text. When the screen-space is limited however, the main-content needs a minimum size to be effective, which means the RichTextBox should fit into a small area with a scrollbar. In a large screen-space, I don't want the RichTextBox taking up too much space that it doesn't use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide and conquer

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        MinWidth="200" MinHeight="300" Width="200" Height="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:HeightConverter x:Key="HeightConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <!--MainGrid-->
    <Grid Name="grid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--AlignmentGrid-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="180"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto">
                </RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Name="head" Grid.Row="0" Text="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <Rectangle Name="rect" Grid.Row="1" Fill="Red"/>
            <RichTextBox Grid.Row="2"
                         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                         Margin="0,5,0,0"
                         VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                         BorderBrush="#FF818181"
                         BorderThickness="0.5"
                         Background="#FFEEEEEE"
                         FontSize="14">
                <RichTextBox.MaxHeight>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HeightConverter}">
                        <Binding ElementName="grid" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="head" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="rect" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                        <Binding ElementName="foot" Path="ActualHeight"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </RichTextBox.MaxHeight>
                <FlowDocument>
                    <List>
                        <ListItem>
                            <Paragraph>Lorem</Paragraph>
                            <Paragraph>IpSum</Paragraph>
                            <Paragraph>Lorem</Paragraph>
                            <Paragraph>IpSum</Paragraph>
                        </ListItem>
                    </List>
                </FlowDocument>
            </RichTextBox>
        </Grid>

    <!--Footer-->
        <TextBlock Name="foot" Grid.Row="1" Text="Footer" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Converter:

```
public class HeightConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double gridHeight = (double)values[0];
        double headHeight = (double)values[1];
        double rectHeight = (double)values[2];
        double footHeight = (double)values[3];

        return gridHeight - headHeight - rectHeight - footHeight;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Note that for the Converter to give the desired result, the height of the MainGrid may not exceed the height of the content in the Window.

Comment: I just tried your example and it worked a treat. I've applied the same principle to my core code base and it works fine there too.

When I originally posted the question, I was actually looking for an in-built way that I might be missing, but this solution works without being 'hacky'. I like it. 

Completely up-to-you, but I would be grateful if you could state that this work is now part of the public domain, assuming you're the original author.

Comment: I couldn't figure out a pure XAML solution, this is the closest I got. You're free to use it as you like.

Comment: @BlackBox: _"I would be grateful if you could state that this work is now part of the public domain"_ -- there is no need for anyone to explicitly state that, as it's built into the user agreement for Stack Overflow. All content (code and text) authored by users and posted here is done so under Creative Commons licensing that grants free use. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing. Non-authored content must be properly attributed to the original author/copyright-holder, and the person posting must ensure it's legal for them to post it under shareable terms.