# How to automatically constraint rows/columns minimal size when using proportional grid sizing (*)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Assuming we have a simple window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Width="300" Height="300">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Row="0" Margin="2,2,2,2">
            <TextBlock
                Text="Button 1.&#x0a;It has some text.&#x0a;Button shouldn't shrink less then the text size."
                TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
        </Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Button 2" Margin="2,2,2,2" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: Normal size]

Seems ok. However, after resizing, the upper button's content is cropped:
[image: Small size]

The desired layout should look like this:

[image: Desired behaviour]

In text: **make the row height behave as proportional (*) with `MinHeight` equal to it's `Auto` height. In other words, have the `Height` to be `Max(1*,Auto)`.**

I assume that if WPF is capable of determining size of row automatically when set to `Auto`, then there should be a way to make it respect that size when proportionally sizing.

I found somewhat related questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860046/limit-rows-height-on-both-auto-and-1-in-wpf), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37810682/wpf-grid-auto-sizing-with-minimum-height-constraints)) but was unable to adapt techniques used there to my case.

The only result achieved at the moment is

- Bind `Button.MinHeight` to nested `TextBlock.ActualHeight`
- In code behind: enumerate all grid's childs placed in the first row, find maximal `MinHeight`, set it as `RowDefinition.MinHeight`. Looks crappy because the button is bigger then the text block.

May be something related to `Measure & Arrange` is needed? Or it is not worth the effort and it would be better to just place `MinHeight` manually (and also have some problems with the localization strings lenght differences)?

Comment: Can you just use 2* for the top RowDefinition Height

Comment: @paparazzo I can, but it will not prevent content from cropping when shrinking to some point (although it will definitely happen later then when using `1*`).  And the first button will always be much bigger then second even when there is enough space so they can be sized equally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick and easy trick.

Duplicate the control (and hide it) and use its measurements to find the `MinHeight`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="dummyControl" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Margin="2,2,2,2" Visibility="Hidden" IsHitTestVisible="False">
            <TextBlock
                Text="Button 1.&#x0a;It has some text.&#x0a;Button shouldn't shrink less then the text size."
                TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
        </Button>
    </Grid>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition MinHeight="{Binding ElementName=dummyControl, Path=ActualHeight}" Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Row="0" Margin="2,2,2,2">
            <TextBlock
                Text="Button 1.&#x0a;It has some text.&#x0a;Button shouldn't shrink less then the text size."
                TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
        </Button>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Button 2" Margin="2,2,2,2" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

`VerticalAlignment` of `dummyControl` should be anything other than `Stretch`

Comment: this will kill performance if control is more complicated and uses lots of bindings

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't see such a way to get `Auto` size of a control. Although code duplication doesn't seem to be the best solution in terms of maintainability and, as @KrzysztofSkowronek said, perfomance, it does the job.

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek that depends on how efficient the data model is converted into viewModel and how complex is the xaml code. given that it doesn't render twice, it kills a little IMO

Comment: @ArXen42 yes, I agree. this is probably not your real code but you can improve or simplify the dummyControl as necessary. however IMO it's better to alter the design just a little bit in favor of the common wpf layout system